# Windows batch-file - how to ping server chosen from list in a text-file

Tags: file, batch-file

Is it possible to make a batch file which I have a store number to type in then pings the IP. I have a list with these store numbers and IP's.

I want the user to type in a store number and script will associate store number with IP.

How do I even start going about this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and you should start by searching, [there are many examples](https://www.google.com/#q=batch-file+ping+address+user+input). Then try adapting the code and in case of problems edit the question, add the code, describe the *specific* problem because currently the question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just don't know what exactly I am searching for.

Comment: I just know that I have a variable and I want to associate an IP to it. Do I use store number as varible for IP? I don't understand the wording to make my point come across...its similar to the list and slice command in python I suppose.

Comment: I suppose an example would look like: 000010 10.x.x.x   user would type the store number 000010 and script will ping the IP address related on the same line in the file

Comment: If my anwer solved your problem, please mark it as approved, so it will be easier for people to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a file called `list.txt` containing a list of numbers and addresses such as this:

```
001 google.com
002 stackoverflow.com
003 random.org
004 127.0.0.1
```

You can use the following batch-file to call ping on address with selected number:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%I IN (list.txt) DO ( 
    IF [%%I] EQU [%1] (
        PING %%J
    )
)
```

For example (if you name the batch-file as `ping-selected.bat`):

```
C:\Script>ping-selected 001

Pinging google.com [216.58.209.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.209.46: bytes=32 time=6 TTL=58
Reply from 216.58.209.46: bytes=32 time=6 TTL=58
Reply from 216.58.209.46: bytes=32 time=6 TTL=58
Reply from 216.58.209.46: bytes=32 time=6 TTL=58

Ping statistics for 216.58.209.46:
packets: sent = 4, Received = 4, lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-secounds:
Minimum = 6 ms, Maximum = 6 ms, Average = 6 ms
```